# tsconfig.json and external references

Tags: typescript

I have a web project which uses typescript and I have the following (pseudo )file structure:

```
.
|_externaldeps
|_tssrc
|_test
|_tsoutput
|_typings
```

**externaldeps** contains external libraries, such as Angular, Jquery etc but also some company internal libraries which contains d.ts-files.

**tssrc** contains my source files

**test** contains karma tests which are written in Typescript.

**tsoutput** contains the result of transpiling tssrc

**typings** contains d.ts files from DefinetlyTyped

My problem is how to configure tsconfig.json for this. Tssrc needs to know about everyting but the test folder, the test folder basically just needs to know about the tssrc folder etc.

How could this be solved? Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? What do you mean by 'needs to know'? Maybe [this](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/how-to-create-strongly-typed-npm-modules-1e1bda23a7f4#.1b6jcuj4r) is a helpful post.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a task runner tool like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) it will make your life easier in the long term...

The following is an example of the configuration used to compile some unit tests and source with Gulp:

```
// The TypeScript compiler settings
var tsProject = tsc.createProject({
  removeComments : false,
  noImplicitAny : false,
  target : "ES5",
  module : "commonjs",
  declarationFiles : false
});

// compile app code
gulp.task("build-source", function() {
  return gulp.src(__dirname + "/source/*.ts")
             .pipe(tsc(tsProject))
             .js.pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + "/build/source/"));
});

var tsTestProject = tsc.createProject({
  removeComments : false,
  noImplicitAny : false,
  target : "ES5",
  module : "commonjs",
  declarationFiles : false
});

// compile test code
gulp.task("build-test", function() {
  return gulp.src(__dirname + "/test/*.test.ts")
             .pipe(tsc(tsTestProject))
             .js.pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + "/build/test/"));
});
```

Note: I use two separated ``tsc.createProject` because using the same two times with different input and output folders can lead to unexpected behavior.

The full example is available [here](https://github.com/remojansen/TypeScriptTestingExamples). Take a look to the `gulpfile.js` file.